# WebdriverIO - Take full-page screenshot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io, wdio-v4

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the full page using WebdriverIO.

I've read that the best method is to use [WebdriverCSS](https://github.com/webdriverio-boneyard/webdrivercss) to enhance my WebdriverIO flows. WebdriverCSS automatically screenshots the entire page??

The problem is that WebdriverCSS is not working for me. I think it's because it is not yet compatible with `webdriverio@3.0.x`.

Is there any way to make it work or another solution that I could use?

**My code:** (*which is producing nothing but undefined values in the callback*)

```
// Initialize WebdriverCSS for `client` instance
require('webdrivercss').init(driver, {
    // example options
    screenshotRoot: '../../screenshots',
    failedComparisonsRoot: '../../screenshots/diffs',
    misMatchTolerance: 0.05
});

// ...
// driver gets initialized and url opened
// ...

driver.webdrivercss('page', {
  name: 'body',
  elem: 'body'
}, function(err, res) {
  // here the values of err and res are always undefined
})
.saveScreenshot('../../screenshots/webdrivercsstest.png');
// the screenshot works, but it's not full page
```

**!EDIT:**
This is a known BUG in Chromium which most likely will not be fixed. Please see [this LINK](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294) for more details.

Comment: Hey @mags! Probably this isn't of interest to you anymore, but I posted a working way to achieve this easily for others visiting the question.

Comment: Also for clarification, that blogpost & the wording can be a bit misleading... it isn't for the Selenium, or Driver teams (*gheckodriver*, *chromedriver*, *etc.*) to implement such a feature. Apart from the obvious rendering issues, which still stand... it's logical that this should only be done at a high-level framework level (e.g: WebdriverIO, Puppeteer).

Comment: Selenium is (quoting the docs) ***a user-centric web-testing framework***. Adding something a user **can't do**, like look at an entire page without scrolling (*duh!*) isn't something the team will ever do. Everything in Selenium is implemented in regard to this. (*text is added letter-by-letter*, as a user would type it, *first element is always clicked first*, like a user would, *you cannot click an element you cannot see*, like a user would). You get the idea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can probably be done in quite a handful of ways, but the most straight forward way would be via the **[wdio-screenshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-screenshot)** WebdriverIO plugin.

1. Install the plugin: `npm install --save-dev wdio-screenshot`
2. Enable the plugin in the `wdio.conf.js` file in the `plugings` object: `plugins: { 'wdio-screenshot': {} }`
3. Inside your test, add the following step (*for a document(full-page screenshot*): `browser.saveDocumentScreenshot('<screenShotsPath>/screenshotName.png');`

**>** The full-page screenshot looks like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nvru.jpg)** for an Instagram feed attempt. (*left the screenshot inline for obvious reasons*)

- **!Note-001:** If you don't want your screenshot to look like that, then I recommend you use some *[waitUntil](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html)* to guarantee your content has *loaded & rendered successfully*.
- **!Note-002:** `wdio-screenshot` supports 3 types of screenshots (*viewport* (standard), *document* (full-page) & *element* (element-targeted)).

Comment: I got this error


TypeError: browser.saveDocumentScreenshot is not a function
    at H:\webdriver\webdriverio-test\test.js:17:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: how to check is plugin loaded or not?

Comment: ok, it seems like wdio-screenshot doesn't work with webdriverio v5

Comment: @SergeyL, hmm... yeah, this was surely executed on a `webdriverio@4.x.x`. I'll try to update the answer with the **v5** way in the near future. Thanks for pointing that out man!

Comment: @SergeyL Try browser.saveScreenshot

Comment: @iamdanchiv I have already seen that. Using the accepted green tick answer.
But I when I am using browser.saveDocumentScreenshot('folder/filename.png')
I am getting error as browser.saveDocumentScreenshot is not a function

Comment: Got this error too.. Seems wdio-screenshot is a crap lol

Comment: This link https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-screenshot shows how to use three types  of screenshots. browser.saveDocumentScreenshot([fileName], [{options}]), what is the correct way of writing filename and option while using the command?

Answer (score 2):

@mags : I see that you need screenshots to understand the failure points. I would like to share what i use for screenshots.

1. Integrate allure report to the `wdio.conf` file like this
   `reporterOptions: {
   allure: {
     outputDir: "allure-results"
   },`
2. Install allure using `npm install @wdio/allure-reporter --save-dev`
3. After you execute your test suite, run this command to generate allure results
   `allure generate ./allure-results --clean`
4. Once the above command execution is complete, run the command `allure open`.
5. Now for any test failed, allure will also show you the screenshot captured.
   Please see a sample screenshot attached[image]

Comment: Allure generates **a view-port screenshot**. OP was looking for a way to capture a screenshot of **the entire document**. Anyways, it seems that OP is no longer interested in the fate of this question.

Comment: @Seema Nair, No need to write anything on hooks?

Comment: Hey !!
thanks for this comment. I was using allure but never saw the screenshot thing in the dashboard. Thanks for this answer. It saved a lot of hours :)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried passing a higher div id and take a screen shot of that

```
browser
    .init()
    .url("https://search.yahoo.com")
    .webdrivercss('startpage',[
            {
                name: 'fullpage',
                elem: '#purple-syc'
            }
```

edit: I am also able to see full page screenhot when doing

```
.saveScreenshot('./webdrivercss.png');
```

[image: yahoo home page]

use `.scroll('#myElement')` to scroll and take screen shot again

Comment: Do you get a full screenshot in Chrome? I'm using Chrome 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit). I've heard that some browsers produce full screenshots and some don't.

Comment: @mags yes, I get full page screen shot in chrome as shown above. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010103/webdriverio-browsermob/37011601#37011601) is how to use chrome, in case you need.

Comment: @mags  my chrome version -  50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)

Comment: hmm. I don't think you are getting a full page screenshot. Looks like you're just getting the viewport from the picture you posted.

Comment: @mags increase `viewport`or `scrolldown` to specific position.

Comment: Hey @mags! Did you get to try my solution? It's quick and easy. Cheers!