# in a fullpage screenshot, I want to show all of the content, how can I get scrollable elements' content height together efficient?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, dom-traversal

**fullpage** screenshot, I need to know content height when I don't know how many elements have scrollbar.

traverse the node tree to **find scrollable elements**(maybe div
or others) with code below, by sum all scrollHeight I can set the selenium webdriver's window size then do screenshot.

```
if (node.scrollHeight > node.clientHeight) {
  return node;
}
```

Is there any **example or more efficient** way to do the fullpage screenshot in selenium?

I've tried html2canvas, with some problems like bg and font difference so gave it up.

Answer (score 0):

This can be answered by:

[How to get screenshot of full webpage using Selenium and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085722/how-to-get-screenshot-of-full-webpage-using-selenium-and-java)

Look for the comment related to AShot if you want a full page screenshot.